# Using OR condition in MDX with different hierarchies of same dimension

Tags: mdx

I would like to get data from cube where [Product].[Product Level2].&[S1050]&[S1050.080] OR [Product].[Product Level4].&[S1060.012.701003]. **So combine two hierarchies from same measure in set.**

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { 
    [Measures].[Product Sales], [Measures].[Sales Quantity] 
} ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY { (
    [Product].[EAN CODE].[EAN CODE].ALLMEMBERS 
    * [Product].[Product].[Product].ALLMEMBERS 
    * [Date].[Calender Week].[Calender Week].ALLMEMBERS 
    * [Store].[Store Code].[Store Code].ALLMEMBERS 
    * [Store].[Store].[Store].ALLMEMBERS 
) } ON ROWS 
FROM ( 
        SELECT ( -{ [Store].[Store Code].&[0032], [Store].[Store Code].&[0033] } ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( 
            SELECT ( { [Date].[Calender Week].&[2019]&[IW201906] } ) ON COLUMNS FROM [Cube]
        )
    )
WHERE ( 
    {[Product].[Product Level2].&[S1050]&[S1050.080], [Product].[Product Level4 Code].&[S1060.012.701003]}
)
```

The above query is returning "**Members, tuples or sets must use the same hierarchies in the  function.**"

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your where like this

{(
[Product].[Product Level2].&[S1050]&[S1050.080], [Product].[Product Level4 Code].defaultmember),
{[Product].[Product Level2].defaultmember, [Product].[Product Level4 Code].&[S1060.012.701003]}
)